# Codeigniter 3 blog: echo author's name instead of id, without using an SQL Join

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I am working on a basic *blog application* in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

I use 2 tables: *authors* and *posts*.

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  birthdate date NOT NULL,
  added timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE posts (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  author_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  description varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  content text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The *get_post* method of the *Posts model* gets the single post data:

```
public function get_post($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('id' => $id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Inside the *Posts* controller I have:

```
 public function post($id) {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();

    $this->load->model('Posts_model');
    $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

    if (!empty($data['post'])) {
        // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
        $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('post');
    } else {
        $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('404');
    }
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

Finally inside the *post view*:

```
<main class="content">
  <h2 class="post-title display-4"><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>
  <div class="row post-meta">
    <div class="left-half col-sm-9">
      <span class="author">By <a href="#"><?php echo $post->author_id; ?></a></span> | <span class="date"> <?php echo $post->created_at; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="right-half col-sm-3">
      <a class="comments" href="#" title="98 comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 98</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/800" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <?php echo $post->content ?>
  </div>
  <?php $this->load->view("partials/comments");?>
</main>
```

Of course, this renders the author's *id* instead of his/her name, in the *single post* page.

Since we are talking of **individual posts**, I have a hunch the author's name can be echoed out, **without using an SQL Join**.

How can i do that, in a very Codeigniter  specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If joining table is not an option, then make another query inside your get_post for author's name:

```
public function get_post($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('id' => $id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->row();
        // run separate query for author name
        $author_query = $this->db->get_where('authors', array('id' => $data->author_id));
        if ($author_query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $author = $author_query->row();
        $data->first_name = $author->first_name;
        $data->last_name = $author->last_name; 
        } else {
            $data->first_name = 'Unknown';
            $data->first_name = 'Unknown';
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database call for post data should join to the author table. Something like this should work. You can tweak to select which fields you needs, return array or object, and return different types depending on the result of the query.

```
public function get_post($id) {
    $this->db->select('posts.id, posts.title, authors.first_name, authors.last_name');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query->result_array();
    return isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : false;
}
```